# Which tool is used to identify whether the method have a test cases or not?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, testcase

I'm working on the project in a mid-level company.But i don't have any tool to identify whether the method have the test cases or not. So now i manually go and check whether the method has the test cases or not. So, if you know any tool to identify this cases related to me . Please suggest me an idea. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Check out Cobertura, Jacoco, Emma. If you use Maven, then checkout the Maven plugin for Cobertura. If you use an IDE like IntelliJ, it has awesome built-in code coverage tools when you run JUnit test cases. Hope this helps.

Comment: @kctang, thanks for your reply. it's very helpful to me also.

Comment: @kctang, i'm using the IBM Websphere so please suggest me which one is better.

Answer (score 1):

This [article](http://ibiblio.org/java/slides/albany/codecoverage/Measuring_JUnit_Code_Coverage.html) lists various JUnit code coverage metrics.

[Eclemma](http://www.eclemma.org/) is another interesting too on JUnit code coverage and its free.

Comment: glad, and if u like the answer you can always accept it as customary in SO, though your option is much respected.